# How to create a List view in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.ios, tableview

I want to create a listview with multiple fields and image. I am used table view for developing list view, but I wont get the correct design.

Please help me...

Here is my code

```
    class TableViewSource : UITableViewSource
     {
    List<Sample> tabledata;

    public TableViewSource(List<Sample> items)
    {
        tabledata = items;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell") as CustomVegeCell;
        if (cell == null)
        cell.UpdateCell(tabledata[indexPath.Row].CaseID
                , tabledata[indexPath.Row].Description
                , UIImage.FromFile("right_arrow.png"));
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return tabledata.Count;
    }

    public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        if (indexPath.Row == tabledata.Count - 1)
        {
            //Reload your data here
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewController.cs

```
    List<Sample> _itemdata;
    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        DAtaBinding();
        mainTable.Source = new TableViewSource(_itemdata);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

    }

    public void DAtaBinding()
    {
        _itemdata = new List<Sample>() { { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Aswathy"} },
                                         { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Anu"}},
                                         { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Anu"}},
                                         { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Anu"}},

                                         { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Anu"}},
                                         { new Sample { CaseID="CQ964C",Description="Anu"}},

                              };
    }
}
```

Here is my custom tableviewcell

CustomVegeCell.cs

```
   public class CustomVegeCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel;
    UIImageView imageView;
    public CustomVegeCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(218, 255, 127);
        imageView = new UIImageView();
        headingLabel = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 22f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };
        subheadingLabel = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("AmericanTypewriter", 12f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(38, 127, 0),
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };
        ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { headingLabel, subheadingLabel, imageView });

    }
    public void UpdateCell(string caption, string subtitle, UIImage image)
    {
        imageView.Image = image;
        headingLabel.Text = caption;
        subheadingLabel.Text = subtitle;
    }
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        imageView.Frame = new CGRect(ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 5, 33, 33);
        headingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(5, 4, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
        subheadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(100, 18, 100, 20);
    }
}
```

After adding the custom tableviewcell i got an exception in the  GetCell method

I want this design for my screen
[image]

Comment: Here is some sample code, may be you can get some idea: [Click](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-tableview-in-xamarin-ios/)

Comment: @Ankita I also used this link, but I want the design like the above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to new a class inherit from `UITableViewCell`, and create custom cell layouts in it.

In this scenario you need three labels and a arrow image, and adjust their frame as demonstrated.

Toturial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/customizing-table-appearance).

Sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/WorkingWithTables/).

Comment: @Aswathy what is the exception message？

Comment: Xia-MSFT System.NullReferenceException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Comment: Xia-MSFT I solved my issue , it's a mistake from my side...,thanks for your response. Your link solved my problem